# java8 simplify transformations to map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have this class structure:

```
public class A {
    private List<B> bs;
...//getters
}

public class C {
    private Long id;
...//getters
}

public class B {

    private Long idOfC;
...//more stuff
}
```

B::getIdOfC matches C::getId

**In a better design B would just contain a reference to C, rather than its id (I cannot change that), so that's why now I need to create a map**, so my method signature looks like this

```
public Map<A, List<C>> convert(Collection<A> collection)
```

Inside this convert method, there is a

```
List<C> getCsByIds(List<Long> id)
```

that's later used to match it against B.idOfC, but there should only be one call to this method as it's pretty expensive.

So If I go like this:

```
 List<B> bs = Arrays.asList(new B(10L), new B(11L)); //10L and 11L are the values of idOfC
   List<A> as = Arrays.asList(bs);
   //And assuming getCsByIds returns Arrays.asList(new C(10L), new C(11L), new C(12L));
```

then

```
    Map<A, List<C>> map = convert(as);
    map.values().get(0)
```

returns something like `Arrays.asList(new C(10L), new C(11L))`

The method that does this is pretty massive in my view:

```
    public Map<A, List<C>> convert(Collection<A> as) {
    List<Long> cIds = as.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream())
            .map(B::getCId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //single call to gsCsByIds
    Map<Long, C> csMap = getCsByIds(cIds)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, Function.identity()));

    //a whole new map is created by iterating over the list called "as"
    Map<A, List<C>> csByAs = new HashMap<>();
    if (!csMap.isEmpty()) {
        for (A a : as) {
            Set<C> cs = getCsFromMap(csMap, a.getBs());
            if (!cs.isEmpty()) {
                csByAs.put(a, new ArrayList<>(cs));
            }
        }
    }

    return csByAs;
}

private Set<B> getCsFromMap(Map<Long, C> cMap, List<B> bs) {
    return bs.stream()
            .map(b -> cMap.get(b.getIdOfc()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Is there a way to make this simpler???

Comment: Guess multimap https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html could help to make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the call to `getCsByIds` is expensive, your initial idea is pretty decent to execute itself. It can further be cut short to :

```
public Map<A, List<C>> convert(Collection<A> as) {
    List<Long> cIds = as.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream())
            .map(B::getIdOfC)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Map<Long, C> csMap = getCsByIds(cIds).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, Function.identity()));

    return as.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                    a -> a.getBs().stream().map(b -> csMap.get(b.getIdOfC()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()), (a, b) -> b));
}
```

where you can choose your merge function `(a,b) -> b` accordingly.

Comment: Note: The above code is not using `getCsFromMap` either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just iterate over the As directly? (no compiler at hand, so maybe the snippet is not compile-ready)

```
public Map<A, List<C>> convert(Collection<A> as) {
  Map<A, List<C>> result = new HashMap<>();
  for(A a: as){
     List<Long> cIds = a.getBs().stream()
                         .map(B::getIdOfC)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
     result.put(a, getCsByIds(cIds));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention before that getCsByIds is a pretty expensive call, so it'd be best to call it just once. How could this be changed to fit that?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work? I don't have a compiler so I can't really test it

```
public Map<A, List<C>> convert(Collection<A> as) {
    return as.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function::identity,
                                       a -> a.getBs().stream()
                                                     .map(B::getIdOfC)
                                                     .flatMap(id -> getCsByIds(asList(id))
                                                                   .values()
                                                                   .stream())
                                                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                      )
                     );
}
```

Comment: would be possible to make a single call to getCsByIds, since it's rather expense?

Comment: Sure, but why is it so expensive

Comment: it's a call to service that connects to a database

Comment: Just as I've seen a lot of premature optimization in my life: is it really expensive? meaning: does it REALLY make a difference (have you measured it) to call it 1x for all IDs or multiple times for a fraction of IDs each?